# How can I combine these two shapes with shape builder?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

Basically I want to keep *upper edge more curved* and the *lower edge less curved* but with ***shape builder*** tool I am not able to do this and while viewing the same scenario in outline mode I am getting this .

---

[image: Outline Mode - OFF]

[image: Outline Mode - ON]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that your shapes are expanded `'Object' > 'Expand Appearance'`. Seems to me like the rounded corners aren't "commited" to the objects.